# Why do `select` and `sub` have brackets around them in VB Linq expressions?

Tags: vb.net, linq, c#-to-vb.net

I converted the following query from C#:

```c#
src.Select((c, i) => src.Substring(i)).Count(sub => sub.StartsWith(target))
```

to the VB.NET query:

```vb
src.[Select](Function(c, i) src.Substring(i)).Count(Function([sub]) [sub].StartsWith(target))
```

Using [Developer Fusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).  I was just wondering why the VB.NET version has [] throughout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`select` and `sub` are keywords in VB.NET

Answer (score 5):

[**`Sub`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz1z94ha%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [**`Select`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) are keywords in VB.NET, so you have to mark them especially to be able to use them as variable names - in general using keywords as variable names should be avoided - just rename them and you can get rid of the braces.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why is that both `Select` and `Sub` are reserved words in VB.Net.  The `[]` surrounding them is an escaping mechanism that causes them to not be treated as keywords

Answer (score 0):

A minor point: the `.Select` doesn't need the brackets:

```
src.Select(Function(c, i) src.Substring(i)).Count(Function([sub]) [sub].StartsWith(target))
```

works fine.